# Git - update only files existing in current branch

Tags: git, version-control

I have 2 branches in my local repo - master(core files) and master_with_adds(core + additional configuration)

- **master**

  - system/
  - libs/
- **master_with_adds**

  - system/
  - libs/
  - adds/

All 2 branches contain same files but `master_with_adds` contains additional folder. Now I switched to `master_with_adds`, make some changes and commit it. How can I update my `master` branch with only files existing in `master`? i.e. I have to copy only `system` and `libs`, folder `adds` must not be copied.

SOLVED: I've found the answer here [git 'merge' only existing files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8769377/git-merge-only-existing-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the changes you want brought over don't include adding or removing files, you can

```
git checkout master
git ls-files -z \
| xargs -0 git checkout master_with_adds --
```

and you're done.  If you do want to import additions and removals easiest is probably to do those by hand, starting from there, although you can implement the complete procedure by using the `GIT_INDEX_FILE` environment variable to construct a sideband index of your complete desired state by feeding selected `git ls-tree` output to `git update-index --index-info`, then `git write-tree`ing that, and `git read-tree -um`ing the resulting tree to complete the transition.  That strikes me as a bit overkill here.

Comment: Ah! Nice solution! I like it )

Answer (score 0):

git checkout will do it. Something like:

```
$ git branch
* master
  master_with_adds
$ git checkout master_with_adds /system /libs
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .....
#   new file:   .....
#
$ git commit -m "'Merge' code from 'master_with_adds' branch"
[master]: created 4d3e37b: "'Merge' code from 'master_with_adds' branch"
4 files changed, 72 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
create mode 100644 ...
```

Comment: The problem with this is it won't update only files existing in the current branch.